# PHP mail successful with empty to parameter

Tags: php

I am learning PHP and from what I understand the `mail` function has a `to` parameter that needs to comply with a certain string format - [php doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). I have read that if I parse an empty string then the mail function will return false (not 1). However, when I try this the mail function never fails. Is there something I have missed?

Code:

```
<?php

if (mail('', 'mySubject', 'myMessage')) {
    echo "Success!";

} else {
    echo 'Failure!';
}

?>
```

The output is "Success!"

Only by removing the argument entirely gets the else statement to execute. Does the `to` parameter need to be of a certain string format like the documentation states and if not, then how can I get this function to fail? Thanks

Comment: If just for testing purposes: `if (mail() && false)`. I would be using some mailing libraries like PhpMailer, because `mail` is not very reliable and you will face even bigger problems when email does not come

Comment: `mail()` just hands off the parameters to the mailer daemon running on your system. `mail()` returning `true` just means that this handoff succeeded. Likely the system's mail daemon will later throw an error internally when trying to actually process this mail.

Comment: PHP documentation was not very clear on this. I have also heard PhpMailer is the better option. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mail()` function does not validate the input. It more or less just takes the data and hands it over to the system mailer daemon.

If that handoff was successful, the method returns true.

It it likely that your local mailer daemon will log an error that it couldn't process the email

Comment: It is strange because the doc seems to suggest it does and videos I have seen show people using an empty string to get the function to fail. Confusing that this has changed and nothing is checked now. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: It's quite possible that some daemons will instantly fail and thus cause an error in php. But I'm not 100% sure

Answer (score 1):

php `mail()` function is just a middle-man between your mail daemon and your code.
You need to manually validate email addresses, typically using something like

```
if( filter_var( $email_address ,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) )
{
    mail(parameters);
}
else {
// handle error
}
```

Like @skaveRat said, you'll most probably find something in your email daemon log that this mail was not sent.